# Upstart PID files in home directory?

Tags: files, home-directory, upstart, 15.10

What are all of these PID files doing in my home directory?

```
$ ls -1 ~/upstart-*
/home/mark/upstart-dbus-bridge.4885.pid
/home/mark/upstart-file-bridge.4885.pid
/home/mark/upstart-udev-bridge.10317.pid
/home/mark/upstart-udev-bridge.4885.pid
/home/mark/upstart-udev-bridge.6044.pid
/home/mark/upstart-udev-bridge.6406.pid
/home/mark/upstart-udev-bridge.6650.pid
```

Most are current.  If I try to remove them, they will (eventually) come back (albeit with new IDs, etc.).

`ps` shows the following, for example:

```
4 S mark      4885  5319  0  80   0 - 27317 poll_s Nov21 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/upstart --user
```

The same is happening for other users on the same system as well.

Per Jos's comment, the setups of `/run` / `/var/run` appear to be correct:

```
$ mount|grep run
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1633648k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)

$ ll /var/run
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct 28  2013 /var/run -> /run/
```

Surely this isn't by design, or that there must be a better place to keep these?  As-is, they are not hidden files, nor are they in a hidden directory.  This is messy, and result in a longer listing of things I need to look through in what should otherwise be a very clean and organized `~`.

I think this started after one of my last upgrades which included systemd.  Is this typical, or do I maybe have something else here influencing this that I need to further investigate?  (I have gotten a bit lazy here on this system, and haven't performed a clean install for the past few releases - maybe time for a clean install?)

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"
```

(This would seem to be something that should be resolved by a simple search, but my Google-fu appears to be failing me with this concern.)

Comment: These `pid` files ought to be created in `/var/run` which is a symbolic link to `/run`. They are written every time you connect an USB device. I suspect the `/run` folder, in itself a `tmpfs` file system, is accidentally mounted in your home directory. Please edit your question and add the output of `mount` (or `mount | grep run`).

Comment: @Jos - additional information provided as requested.  They appear correct - but also, if one of these were mounted to inside my home directory, wouldn't this only affect my own home directory, and not the other accounts on the system as well?

Comment: OK, different approach. I'm beginning to think that the `upstart-udev-bridge` process and the others are not executed as root, and are therefore not allowed to write the pid file to `/var/run`; they fall back to writing it to the user's home directory.

Comment: @Jos - Agreed, which is also supported by the ps listing.  So I'm curious if this is "normal"?  I.E., do you or anyone else see the same on an Ubuntu 15.10 installation - or do I have something amiss here?  I can understand the PID files needing to be in my home directory for user-owned processes - but they should be hidden somehow, and not cluttering the top of my home directory...

Comment: I notice that on my 15.10 system I have all of these processes running as my user. I don't see any .pid files anywhere, but I have no USB-connected network devices. I'll take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: I think I solved this one. From looking at the [source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/1.13.2-0ubuntu16) I found out that the .pid file is written to a directory given by the environment variable `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. On my system it is set to `/run/user/1000`. And indeed, on my system that directory does contain my .pid files. So your variable `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` hasn't been set, or not correctly. Am I right?

Comment: @Jos - correct, I do not have this defined, and I can't determine from any Google searching where this should be.  Not sure how I would find this short of doing a clean install elsewhere to compare against, but guessing I may be missing something in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or such as part of an upgrade.  Any chance you'd be able to determine where this is defined on your system?  If so, please provide with a summary of the above as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Am still looking which component could be misbehaving on your system - either systemd, logind, pam or something else. Meanwhile, could you search your syslog for related messages containing "pam", "runtime" and/or "failed"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These files are there because several components in your system conform to the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) and expect the environment variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to be set. If not set, the user's home directory is used.

`pam-systemd` is the component that sets XDG_RUNTIME_DIR to `/run/user/$UID`, where $UID is the effective user id for the user. In your case, `pam-systemd` has not run or has otherwise misbehaved, that is hard to tell. But you can easily set the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR at boot time yourself, as follows: `sudo nano /etc/profile` and add the following lines:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$UID
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

From the next reboot on, the .PID files will no longer clutter your home directory.

Comment: I have similar issues. I added the lines which you mentioned in .bashrc file, not in /etc/profile. Will that work ? Also is it safe to delete existing upstart pid files which are cluttering up home directory?

Comment: I am not completely sure whether it will work. Nothing will break, however you may keep seeing `.pid` files in your home directory. In any case they can be safely deleted.